# When saving to database, how can I check if a field has changed?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I'm using gorm as a Golang ORM. I need to detect **is_active** field has changed to trigger a update on a thirdy-party API service.

I know there is Changed function for Update&Updates. But I need to do this with the Save method.

My Save func:

```
func (r *Repository) Save(form *models.Account) error {
    return r.Connection.MysqlDB().Omit(clause.Associations).Save(form).Error
}
```

My BeforeUpdate Hook:

```
func (m *Account) BeforeUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    //I have to control is_active column here
    return nil
}
```

After save function it continue with BeforeUpdate hook. I have to control in there.

Comment: As I understand, you can follow this https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Check-Field-has-changed. Hope it work to you.

Comment: @nohattee yes I know that. But it is working with Update&Updates functions. I need with Save function.